# Playframework 2.0 logging with JBOSS 7.1

Tags: playframework, jboss7.x

From several days I am trying to configure the logs of my playframework applicatin but it appeared to be a tough job, because "Play2 and JBoss7 don't "play" well together". I am generating the war file with [Play2War plugin](https://github.com/dlecan/play2-war-plugin) and I tried everything I found on the web for configuring the logs, but nothing worked... So is there someone, who has done that before to give me something like a small tutorial, because I am really stuck now. I will appreciate any kind of help.

Answer (score 0):

If I recall correctly the issue is that the Play framework attempts to remove all log handlers during it's initialization. Which is obviously a problem.

Since however you're using Play2 you might want to checkout [escalante](http://escalante.io/). They've already addressed the logging issue.

Comment: The war file doesn't event contain log folder... And I tried to configure them using the information I found on the web, but nothing works... If someone has done that before and can explain to me what is the problem I would be very grateful!

Comment: Well the war shouldn't contain a log directory. I don't know how Play2 configures logging, the only thing I remember is that Play2 removes all handlers from at least the root logger. Which IMO is a bad thing for an application to do, but that's off topic ;)